# C# Extracting String From ListView

Tags: c#, string

I have an issue where my ListView (when showing as a string variable) keeps showing the items as ListViewItem {//item}. I wondered if there was anyway of extracting the string from between the {}?

The method I have at the moment works but is by no means how I want to be doing this.

```
string item = listView1.Items[i].ToString().Replace("ListViewItem: ", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
```

i is from a for loop, just an incrementing number.

Thanks

Comment: please show the output of `listView1.Items[i].ToString()`

Comment: Is this a ASP, forms or WPF listview?

Comment: @Yahia - the output is ListViewItem {//item}.

Comment: Then I'd say your best answer is use the `.Text` property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but you can use -

```
string item = listView1.Items[i].Text
```

To get the text value of the item.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should be able to use the [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.text.aspx) property:

```
listview1.Items[i].Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideal candidate for regex. If you match the string with the simple regex below, whatever in the group "val" value will be the text you want.

```
ListViewItem: \{(?<val>.*)\}
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but I hate when people do and don't leave comments on why. Before we resort to parsing strings looking for properties of the item would be a more ideal solution such as `.Text` mentioned above. However, they are assuming the OP is using Windows Forms or WPF. Asp.Net's listview works differently.

Comment: Thanks Jay. So to whoever that downvote, comment please? The question is asked on how to extract the text between the {} which is exactly what this answer. Yes maybe there is different way to get the text, but the answer addressing the question

Comment: Thanks Fadrian, I used the .Text view above which works great, but thanks for the suggestion, so I +1 your vote as I +1 everyone who suggests answers to my questions.